# COCOS2d-js view hide by top and bottom bars on iPhone5 [Safari]

Tags: safari, iphone-5, cocos2d-js

Im developing full screen browser based game using cocos2d-js.It is working well.
When I test it on iPhone5 safari browser, Game cover by top and bottom bars.[Image with top and bottom bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnqmq.png)

How to remove this bars or how to set my game to current display area?